# SLIDESHOW ARROWS AND AUTOMATIC TURN

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have a slideshow with 4 images accessed by pressing the corresponding 4 buttons on the bottom. I want to add arrows on the side so it can be easier to change the image and more stylized,and i also want for the slideshow to automatically change images when we don't touch it for 10sec so the page can feel more alive, if it has to use javascript, i will use js.
(ps:sorry for bad english) here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/04yp62og/ (you will have to dezoom cause its a big slideshow)

Heres the slideshow html:

```
<html lang=fr>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BETACSS.css">
        <link type="image/png" href="LOGO.ico">
        <title> Nexxus</title>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0%;padding: 0%;">
        
        <div class="BLOCDIAPO">

            <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
            <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
            <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
            <span id="slider-image-4"></span>

            <div class="CONTENEURIMG">
                <img src="1.png" class="slider-image" alt="God of War : Ragnarok">
                <img src="2.png" class="slider-image" alt="Uncharted : A Thief's End">
                <img src="3.png" class="slider-image" alt="Horizon : Forbidden West">
                <img src="4.png" class="slider-image" alt="The Last of Us : Part II">
            </div>    

            <div class="BOUTTONSPLACE">
                <a href="#slider-image-1" class="BOUTTONSDIAPO"></a>
                <a href="#slider-image-2" class="BOUTTONSDIAPO"></a>
                <a href="#slider-image-3" class="BOUTTONSDIAPO"></a>
                <a href="#slider-image-4" class="BOUTTONSDIAPO"></a>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the css it uses :

```
.BLOCDIAPO{
    width: 1156px;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-width:10px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#272727;
}


.CONTENEURIMG{
    width: 4624px;
    height: 650px;
    position: relative;
    transition: left 2s;
    -webkit-transition: left 2s;
    -o-transition: left 2s;
}


.slider-image{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.BOUTTONSPLACE{
    top: -24px;
    position: relative;
}

.BOUTTONSDIAPO{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

#slider-image-1:target ~ .CONTENEURIMG{
    left: 0px;
}

#slider-image-2:target ~ .CONTENEURIMG{
    left: -1156px;
}

#slider-image-3:target ~ .CONTENEURIMG{
    left: -2312px;
}

#slider-image-4:target ~ .CONTENEURIMG{
    left: -3468px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

I'm a noob i saw this on youtube and barely understood it so changing it ? Nah i can't, this is not on my level yet. I couldn't do nothing which is why i seek help! please!